# Which is the format described 'PAGE' in Xcode 8.2 Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I cloned RxSwift from [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift).

When I opened Rx.playground I faced such a rich document as shown below.

Which is the format of this?
I googled 'xcode page' but the search result is so fuzzy :[

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Markup language for annotating a document.

That is Apple says: "Markup for playgrounds includes page level formatting for headings and other elements, formatting spans of characters, showing inline images, and several other features."

Small example:
[Raw and rendered Markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXLLr.jpg)

For change from raw to render you can select the Show Rendered Markup from the Xcode editing menu.

Markup in playground really powerful instruments for create brilliant documentation.

You can read full [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html)